# Emgu CV Blob Detection -Video Surveillance Example

Tags: opencv, blob, detection, emgucv

I'm trying to perform very basic blob detection with no success.  Simply using the VideoSurveillance example...it compiles and runs fine, but really doesn't detect blobs at all.  The FGDetector seems to work well, so I appear to get a good foreground, but the BlobTrackerAuto.Process hardly ever results in a blob being found...even when there appears to be a very prominent blob in the foregroundMask image.  Here is a code snippet showing how I capture and process the image.

```
void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     Image<Bgr, Byte> frame = _cameraCapture.QueryFrame();

     frame._SmoothGaussian(3); //filter out noises

     _detector.Update(frame);

     Image<Gray, Byte> foregroundMask = _detector.ForegroundMask;                

     _tracker.Process(frame, foregroundMask);

     foreach (MCvBlob blob in _tracker)
     {
        frame.Draw((Rectangle)blob, new Bgr(255.0, 255.0, 255.0), 2);
        frame.Draw(blob.ID.ToString(), ref _font, Point.Round(blob.Center), new Bgr(255.0, 255.0, 255.0));
     }

     Image<Bgr, Byte> frameDisplay = frame.Resize(imageBox1.Width, imageBox1.Height, INTER.CV_INTER_LINEAR, false);
     Image<Gray, Byte> fgMaskDisplay = foregroundMask.Resize(imageBox2.Width, imageBox2.Height, INTER.CV_INTER_LINEAR, false);

     imageBox1.Image = frameDisplay;
     imageBox2.Image = fgMaskDisplay;
  }
```

And this is a sample image from the program, which shows (in my naive opinion) a very obvious blob that is not detected.

[image: Screen shot from my program]

It seems that there must be some way to configure the blob detection (threshold settings?) so that it knows how to discriminate foreground from background.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     Image<Bgr, Byte> frame = _cameraCapture.QueryFrame();

     frame._SmoothGaussian(3); //filter out noises

     _detector.Update(frame);

     Image<Gray, Byte> foregroundMask = _detector.ForegroundMask;                

     _tracker.Process(frame, foregroundMask);

     foreach (MCvBlob blob in _tracker)
     {
        frame.Draw((Rectangle)blob, new Bgr(255.0, 255.0, 255.0), 2);
        frame.Draw(blob.ID.ToString(), ref _font, Point.Round(blob.Center), new Bgr(255.0, 255.0, 255.0));
     }

     Image<Bgr, Byte> frameDisplay = frame.Resize(imageBox1.Width, imageBox1.Height, INTER.CV_INTER_LINEAR, false);
     Image<Gray, Byte> fgMaskDisplay = foregroundMask.Resize(imageBox2.Width, imageBox2.Height, INTER.CV_INTER_LINEAR, false);

     imageBox1.Image = frameDisplay;
     imageBox2.Image = fgMaskDisplay;
  }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.